# Почему нельзя использовать <T super Number> в Generics?

Tags: java, generics

Я хочу ограничить тип, передаваемый в метод, в качестве параметра снизу:

```
public <T super Number> void fill(T list) {}
```

Но IDEA мне подчеркивает, что так делать нельзя.

Хотя когда я делаю такое же ограничение сверху вот так:

```
public <T extends Number> void fill(T list) {}
```

То всё нормально работает.

В чем разница? Почему сверху я ограничение выставить могу, а такое же снизу выставить не получается? Как мне добиться нужного эффекта, используя именно `<T ... >`, а **не** `<? ... >`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если мы пишем `<T super Number>`, то тип `T` у нас может быть любым в иерархии наследования класса `Number`. Притом, что мы об этих классах не знаем ничего, кроме как того, что они наследуются от `Object`. Соотвественно, вызвать какие то методы напрямую у объекта типа `T` у нас не получится.

Ситуация с `<T extends Number>` противоположная. Мы все еще понятия не имеем какой это класс `T`, но абсолютно точно знаем, что у него есть методы, которые определены в классе `Number`, т.к. класс наледуется от `Number`.

Следовательно, конструкция вида `<T super Number>` является бессмысленной. Основной профит ее использования, это применение с параметризированными классами, например `List<? super Number>`

Answer (score 0):

> Соотвественно, вызвать какие то методы напрямую у объекта типа T у нас
>   не получится.

Методы вызвать не получится, а вот если мы допустим захотим сделать приведение типов? К примеру такой метод написать `<T super Number> T getFirst(List<T> list) { return (T) list.get(0); }` что в этом плохого?